# Consul cluster does not work properly when one of server is down

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul

I guess the main purpose of a cluster is failure tolerance. However, when I start the following consul cluster, it is not the case and I don't understand why.

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  # docker network create --driver=bridge discovery-network

  # SERVICE DISCOVERY
  consul-server-0:
    image: consul:1.6.0
    container_name: consul-server-0
    command: "agent -server -bootstrap-expect 2 -client 0.0.0.0 -datacenter datacenter-1 -node consul-server-0"
    networks:
      - discovery-network

  consul-server-1:
    image: consul:1.6.0
    container_name: consul-server-1
    command: "agent -server -retry-join consul-server-0 -client 0.0.0.0 -datacenter datacenter-1  -node consul-server-1"
    networks:
      - discovery-network
    depends_on:
      - consul-server-0

  consul-client-1:
    image: consul:1.6.0
    container_name: consul-client-1
    command: "agent -retry-join consul-server-0 -ui -client 0.0.0.0  -datacenter datacenter-1  -node consul-client-1"
    ports:
      - "8500:8500" # GUI
    networks:
      - discovery-network
    depends_on:
      - consul-server-0

networks:
  discovery-network:
    external:true
```

When I stop one of servers, the cluster does not work anymore. I am unable to register anymore service (through consul-client).

In the remaining server's logs, I can see the message `Failed to make RequestVote RPC`
In the client's logs, I can see the message `No cluster leader`

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with consul is that at some point it wants to reach a quorum to be able to do proper leadership elections. For your servers you're using the `-bootstrap-expect 2` to essentially tell the server to expect two nodes before starting the leadership election.

If you only have 2 nodes, and one is failing(or broken) you'll end up with a split brain situation. The node that is left over, doesn't have enough other nodes left to be able to decide who should be the leader inside the cluster. 
As a result it will not accept any new registrations.

My expectation is, that if you have a cluster of 3 nodes, and one fails, it should be able to continue running. Generally with cluster setups an un-even number of nodes is a good idea and generally (clustersize/2) >= 2

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. I can start another server and expect 3. But if 2 servers are stopped, I fall in the same situation. It seems better to NOT fix the number of server. Is it possible ?

Comment: That is to be expected, this is by design. When forming clusters, they always want a Quorum to have a 'majority' to be able to vote.

If you kill 2 out of 3, this is no longer possible so they can no longer make any guarantees about making good decisions. 
When designing systems to be fault-tolerant, generally you split up your nodes over a set of failure-domains, so you know that even with some failures, you will still maintain a majority. 
A good example of this is spreading your nodes out over multiple availability-zones in a public cloud provider. introducing geographic redundancy.